# Scheme with multiple targets -> Crashlytics -> Unable to copy dSym file

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, dsym

I am building a scheme with multiple targets for Archive.

If I build every single target with corresponding scheme alone, it works just fine.

However, when I am building them altogether in one scheme I get error from crashlytics:

```
2014-05-13 16:47:43.453 run[52789:507] Unable to copy dSYM at path /Users/miroslavkutak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ConTAGme-cohfutczhamcdpcbnpdrtbbzeefh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AppStore/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos to path /Users/miroslavkutak/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac/5b91b14e832a7b1c29441ec5ba109810/builds/0DE12720-9BDE-4BEA-806D-CFD3B9FA119E/travel.app.dSYM Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “DWARF” doesn’t exist." UserInfo=0x1001022c0 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/miroslavkutak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ConTAGme-cohfutczhamcdpcbnpdrtbbzeefh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AppStore/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/travel.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF, NSUserStringVariant=(
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible solution - turn off Parallelize Build in Scheme options.

Comment: How are slower builds a solution?! It's a nasty workaround at best.

Answer (score 1):

Just move Crashlytics build phase to bottom.